# String memory allocation using + operator

Tags: java, string, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

`String a = "abc";`
`String b = "xyz";`
`String result = a + b;`

I was wondering if "result" string is a String constant allocated memory in string pool or a new object created on heap.

I know that new String() creates object on heap and String constants like a,b in the above example in permgen string pool space.

Comment: What does result=="abcxyz" return? That should give you a hint about the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An important note:

```
String a = "abc";
String b = "xyz";
String result = a + b;
```

is the same as

```
// creates a number of objects.
String result = new StringBuilder().append(a).append(b).toString();
```

but

```
final String a = "abc";
final String b = "xyz";
String result = a + b;
```

is the same as

```
String result = "abcxyz"; // creates no new objects.
```

Comment: In other words, since the variables are `final` it can be optimized and the Java compiler is smart enough to do the concatenation at compile time.

Comment: Correct, its one of the few optimisations the `javac` performs. The first example might create 3-5 objects each times it is run, the second example creates none.

Comment: Understood. But looks like if I want to use a+b dynamically(dont know the values of a and b before) then it does create a lot of objects(created by StringBuilder())and its worse if this inside a loop.

Comment: Agreed. If you want to just concatenate two Strings, it can be slightly more efficient to use concat() which doesn't create a StringBuilder. For all other situations (even concatenating three strings) using `+` is fairly efficient.

Comment: `String s = "abc";`   
`String x = "xyz";`  
`String result = s.intern() + x.intern();`                        Thinking of using it the following way but I think this will just flood permgen space if I do this all across the board

Comment: intern() is not a cheap method so it would be slightly slower, otherwise this will do the same thing as the strings are already interned.

Answer (score 2):

If you compile and decompile your code, it will give the following results:

```
String result = new StringBuilder().append(a).append(b).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The concatenation results in the allocation of a StringBuilder to create the concatenated string.

Source:

```
public class Hello {

    public static final String CONST1 = "cafe";
    public static final String CONST2 = "babe";

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String a = "abc";
        String b = "xyz";
        String result = a + b;

        String result2 = CONST1 + CONST2;
    }
}
```

Disassembled via javap:

```
public class Hello extends java.lang.Object{
public static final java.lang.String CONST1;

public static final java.lang.String CONST2;

public Hello();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   ldc     #2; //String abc
   2:   astore_1
   3:   ldc     #3; //String xyz
   5:   astore_2
   6:   new     #4; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
   9:   dup
   10:  invokespecial   #5; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   13:  aload_1
   14:  invokevirtual   #6; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   17:  aload_2
   18:  invokevirtual   #6; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   21:  invokevirtual   #7; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   24:  astore_3
   25:  ldc     #8; //String cafebabe
   27:  astore  4
   29:  return

}
```

You can see the `StringBuilder` allocation at line 10 for concatenating String `a` and `b`. Notice the concatenation of CONST1 and CONST2 is processed by the compiler at line 25. So if your Strings are `final` it will not result in a `StringBuilder` allocation